# SwiftUI Widgets with Siri Intent for dynamic list of options

Tags: swiftui, sirishortcuts, widgetkit

With iOS 14 and the new widgets you can either have a `StaticConfiguration` or an `IntentConfiguration` where you define a custom intent. I have created a simple Intent in the intent configuration file called "MySimpleIntent". Code is generated by Xcode.

I went on and created an Intent Extension in order to provide a dynamic list of options (when editing the widget). Usually the list is always the same with all widgets, however I specifically need to filter the list of results based on the *widget family*.

Do you know how I can retrieve the widget family from an Intent / Intent Configuration? I get can all current widgets using the `WidgetCenter.shared.getConfigurations`, however I can't properly filter them by intent identifier.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it, but on top of my head I guess you can just create a different Intent for the list that you need filtered and add another `func getTimeline` using that IntentConfiguration on the same widget

Comment: I ended up making an intent per size and making a generic timeline provider